# Android login with facebook crash

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have a problem with my app, i'm trying to implement facebook login, I read the guide on developer.facebook.com and i wrote this code

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private Boolean facebookLogin = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            String userID = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
            String facebookToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            facebookLogin = true;
            sendLoginData(userID, facebookToken);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I also modify the manifest like the guide say, but, when i'm running the app, if i click on the facebook login button my app is closed without any apparent error.

I also tryed to execute debug, I placed some breakpoints inside the facebook callback and inside the onActivityResult() but they hasn't been reached.

If i add some permission in loginButton.setReadPermissions() the app open the facebook activity but, when I click on ok, is closed again.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: can you post your logcat

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/19/facebook-integration-in-android/#more-109

Comment: I solved it, i forget that in the manifest I have declared the login activity like activity with no history

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code.

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
    "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        System.out.println("onSuccess");

        String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
            .getToken();
        Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {@Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
            GraphResponse response) {

                Log.i("LoginActivity",
                response.toString());
                try {
                    id = object.getString("id");
                    try {
                        URL profile_pic = new URL(
                            "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
                        Log.i("profile_pic",
                        profile_pic + "");

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    name = object.getString("name");
                    email = object.getString("email");
                    gender = object.getString("gender");
                    birthday = object.getString("birthday");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields",
            "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        System.out.println("onCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        System.out.println("onError");
        Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
    }
});



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
}
```